# No reference on void Start() and Update unity vs code

Tags: unity-game-engine, debugging, visual-studio-code, intellisense

So my intellisense works fine on vs code
However, I used to have references of Unity's inner classes like Start Update etc
It used to be like little unity icon and number of refences written near by
But now it says 0 refences and no unity logo
Any idea on how I could fix that?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCK6x.png)

Comment: Have you tried the steps mentioned at [ScriptingToolsIDEs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptingToolsIDEs.html)?

Comment: @nIcEcOw yes I did, I doubled checked it again but no results

Answer (score 1):

To see references you must have Unity extension installed and set VS Code as default IDE.

[image]

[image]

When you change it restart Unity and after restart hit regenerate project files.

FYI - i am using VS2019 thats reason why i have in editor dropdown VS2019 you will have VS Code

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You missed the part where I said I use Vs Code and not VS.

Comment: Screen with extension is from vs code, on second screen you jist use vscode